# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Why does a dropdown form refresh its parent and not submit?

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown form in my menu:

```
<li class="dropdown animate-click" data-animate="animated fadeInUp" style="z-index:500;">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-form-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-user animate-wr">
      <li id="dropdownForm">
        <div class="dropdown-form">
         <form class="form-default form-inline p-15" name="searchForm" id="searchbox" method="get" action="Search.aspx">
           <div class="input-group">
               <input value="XX" name="cx" type="hidden"/>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What do you want to find?">
               <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn btn-two" type="submit">Go!</button>
               </span>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

However, when I press the submit button, the parent page refreshes and the form does not submit to the `Search.aspx` page (the page that is specified in the `action` tag of the form). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should tag this question with an ASP-related tag

Comment: What I have seen is that the <button> does the refresh of the page.  If you do not want that to happen, use <input type="button" />  This will submit what you want just like a <button> but does not refresh.

Comment: Do you have the form shown here nested inside Webforms's wrapper `form` element? Nested forms are invalid HTML. I think you need to remove the form element shown here and replace your `button` with an `asp:Button` that has a server side click handler. You can then redirect to Search.aspx or whatever.